# Set page title of WebView from fragment

Tags: android, android-webview, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager`, with each view being a `WebView`.  I'd like, if the user clicks on a link in one of the `WebViews`, to set the title of the `Actionbar` to the current web page.

I was hoping I could use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` to do that, but the page title is always the previous page.  So if a user clicks on link 1, then link 2, and link 3.  On page 3 the title of link 2 is being shown in the `Actionbar`.

If I put the title setting code in `onPageFinished`, the page title is being set to the next view of the `ViewPager`, due to the `ViewPager` executing the previous/next views for performance.

**Fragment**

```
public class Browser extends SherlockFragment {

    private OnBrowserSetTitle mBrowserSetTitle;

   @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity act) {
        super.onAttach(act);
        mBrowserSetTitle = (OnBrowserSetTitle)act;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        activity = getActivity();

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        mWebView = (WebView)getView().findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            }

             @Override
             public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                  view.loadUrl(url);
                  if (view.getTitle() != null && view.getTitle().length() > 0)
                  {
                      mBrowserSetTitle.onBrowserSetTitle(mTitle);
                  }

                 return true;
             }            
        });
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class BrowserPager extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements Interfaces.OnBrowserSetTitle {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle icicle)
    {    
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.browser_pager);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBrowserSetTitle(String title) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `onBrowserSetTitle` to have the following definition:

```
@Override
public void onBrowserSetTitle(String title, View view) {
    if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == mViewPager.getAdapter().getItemPosition(view)) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

And then call `onBrowserSetTitle` from `onPageFinished` like so:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    if (view.getTitle() != null && view.getTitle().length() > 0) {
        mBrowserSetTitle.onBrowserSetTitle(mTitle, view);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you might be confused.  I can handle the page title when the user swipes between the views, but if a user is on one particular `WebView` and clicks on a link in the web page itself, that is where I'm having the issue.

Comment: thanks for the response.  If you notice in my original question, I tried `onPageFinished`, however, with the way `ViewPagers` works, they execute the previous and next views, for performance, so if I set the title in `onPageFinished`, as the user swipes, the title is showing the wrong title.

Comment: @KrisB I do understand that, but this will check if the view that is trying to set the title is the current view being displayed, so it shouldn't set the title to that of any view that is not the currently displayed one.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see where you were checking the current item.  I implemented the code, do you know why `mViewPager.getAdapter().getItemPosition(view)` always returns -1?

Comment: @KrisB I think you have to override `getItemPosition` in your `PagerAdapter` to return the correct positions for the views.

Comment: I'm having some trouble trying to figure out how to get the position of the `WebView` using `getItemPosition`.  Do I need to loop through all the views in the `PagerAdapter` in `getItemPosition`?

Comment: never mind, I figured it out.  I was able to check the current page by using a unique id I am passing to the fragment and that got it working.  Thanks for your help.